# Find biggest element in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, range

I am new to python.I don't know much about it but when I did the program it says list index out of range or it doesn't even come.

```
a=[3,7,8,2,4,90,1]
f=0
for i in range(0,7,1):
  for j in range(1,7,1):
      if a[j]>a[i]:
        f=a[j]
print (f)
```

Could you help me with this? Can you tell me the mistakes or any other method(except the one using max() )? Thank you

Comment: Have a look on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_max.htm, (first result on Google). So next time investigate your problem. most of the times when you are new to something, you encounter very basic problems which are already discussed 100 times on the internet. If you can't find a solution post a question on SE.com and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Indexes in Python are 0-based. So for a list with 7 elements, the valid indexes are `[0]` to `[6]`

So this line

```
for j in range(i+1,7,1)
```

Should be

```
for j in range(7)
```

Or better, you could replace this whole code snippet with one line

```
print(max(ls))
```

If you'd like to manually do it using a loop

```
ls=[6,8,3,0,2,4,7]
largest = ls[0]
for num in ls:
    if num > largest:
        largest = num

>>> print(largest)
8
```

Comment: `range(i+1, 7, 1)` will only yield indices from 0 to 6.

Comment: In that case, the code they posted could not have produced that error.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary As `i` will be in the range 0 to 6 (inclusive) `range(i+1, 7, 1)` will only yield indices from 1 to 6

Comment: @halex Yes, indeed. But my point was that it is not the reason of `IndexError` or incorrect output, changing `range(i+1,7,1)` to `range(7)` won't fix anything, the code will still return incorrect answer. The answer should be simply `max(ls)` or use a simple loop that keeps track of max item.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes you are right but I just wanted to clarify on this, not to add another possible cause of confusion for OP.

Comment: @ AshwiniChaudhary,could you tell me how to use the simple loop?

Comment: @AanandhiVB Please see my edit, this is a simple step by step way to find the maximum element in a sequence.

Comment: Thankyou for your kind help.I hope i didn't cause you any trouble.